# Is there a smart way to compute $\sum^{25}_{k=0}\binom {3000}{k} p^k (1-p)^{3000-k}$?

Tags: negative-binomial

I am trying to compute probability, and I give a:

$$\sum^{25}_{k=0}\binom {3000}{k} p^k (1-p)^{3000-k}$$

$$p=0,0001$$$

Is there a smart way to compute it?
Another else, I am thinking about Poisson. What do you think?

Comment: Sums of this type are usually approximated by a normal distribution. Are you allowed to do that?

Comment: Only the first $4$ or so terms matter. Just calculate them.  More or less equivalently, approximate with the Poisson parameter $\lambda=0.3$, and calculate the first few terms. The rest are negligible.

Comment: @ajotatxe: sums of this type are Poisson, *not* normal.

Comment: Isn't the answer just $1$ to a high degree of accuracy? It appears to me the sum of $26$ terms is between $1-10^{-40}$ and $1$.

Comment: It's unclear to me how this sum relates to a [negative binomial distribution.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NegativeBinomialDistribution.html)

Answer (score 1):

The ratio of two successive terms of the sum is

$$\frac p{1-p}\frac{3000-k+1}{k}<0.3$$as of $k=2$.

As $0.3^{25}<10^{-13}$, the tail is neglectible and the sum is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. If $p=c/n$, then $\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\rightarrow e^{-c}\frac{c^k}{k!}$. In other words, the binomial distribution goes to a Poisson for rare events. You can use the above approximation to get a quick estimate, which is equivalent to asking $P(X\le25)$ for a Poisson with $n=3000$, giving $c=0.3$. Only the first few terms will matter.

Answer (score 0):

I use the approximation results given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation):

Let $\mu=3000 \times 0.0001 =0.3$ and $\sigma^2=3000\times 0.0001 \times (1-0.0001)=0.29997.$ Now note that $$\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\sim N(0,1)$$ thus
$$\Pr(X\leq 25)=\Pr\Big(\frac{X-0.3}{\sqrt{0.29997}}\le\frac{25-0.3}{\sqrt{0.29997}}\Big)\simeq \Pr\Big(Z\le45.0981\Big)\simeq 1, $$where $Z\sim N(0,1).$

Comment: In this case $n$ is not nearly large enough to eliminate the skew from the distribution. The outcome $0$ occurs with probability $74$% (approximately) and all other outcomes with non-zero probability are greater. Fortunately $k=25$ is so far out on the rapidly-vanishing tail of this distribution that it doesn't much matter what kind of approximation you use.

Comment: @DavidK I see, very interesting point about the skewness, in fact here the skewness turns out to be 1.82547, far from being zero as you mentioned. Many thanks!